# Nifi List File from multiple paths and route them to their respective destinations

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi

I have 3 files at different locations for which I am using 3 list file processors and then the fetch file processor. Now I want to route these files to their respective destinations which is different for all 3 files. need some help on how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Are the destinations fixed? If not, how are you deciding which flowfile should go where?

Comment: yes the destinations are fixed, say file with name abc has to go into i/j/z and file with name def has to go into path i/j/k

Answer (score 6):

As per the routing logic you had mentioned above, you could have the flow as :

```
ListFile(s) -> FetchFile(s) -> RouteOnAttribute -> PutFile(s)
```

In `RouteOnAttribute`, you could use NiFi Expression Language support. For example, you can have three attributes:

```
destination.one : ${filename:startsWith('abc')}
destination.two : ${filename:startsWith('def')}
destination.three : ${filename:startsWith('xyz')}
```

**Explanation**

You will have three `ListFile` processors connected to three `FetchFile` processors. Then connect the `Success` output of all three processors to `RouteOnAttribute`, and after defining the above three relationships, you can connect the three relations to the relevant `PutFile` processors.

In the above example, the `RouteOnAttribute` routes the files whose name starts with `abc` to the relationship `destination.one`, filenames that begin with `def` goes to `destination.two` and so on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This solution work.. can it possible with single put file processor

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple if else statements and set destination on a flowfile attribute, resulting you can do the same in single processors. You can further tune them by number of threads on a single processor for a clean layout. PFB example assume hostname1 puts file to hostnameX/path1 and hostname2 puts file to hostnameY/path2 :

your new attribute for putfile path = 
${sftp.remote.hostname:equals('hostname1'):ifElse('hostnameX/path1','hostnameY/path2')}

You can further nest ifElse in case of n number of hostnames and their corresponding destinations and use your new attribute as destination.